# Authentification on Wootrade with python

Tags: python-3.x

I wanted to trade on Wootrade with some bots but I have a hard time getting the authentification right..
Here is my code:

```
import time
import hmac
from urllib.parse import urlencode
import requests
import hashlib, json, pprint

YOUR_API_SECRET = "SECRET"
YOUR_API_KEY = "KEY"
api_endpoint = "https://api.staging.woo.network/v1/client/info"


ts = int(time.time() * 1000)
hashedsig = hashlib.sha256(YOUR_API_SECRET.encode('utf-8'))
params = urlencode({
    "signature" : hashedsig,
    "timestamp" : ts,
})
hashedsig = hmac.new(YOUR_API_SECRET.encode(), params.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
userdata = requests.get(api_endpoint,
    params = {
        "x-api-signature": hashedsig,
        "x-api-timestamp": ts,
        "x-api-key": YOUR_API_KEY
    },
    headers = {
        "x-api-signature": hashedsig,
        "x-api-timestamp": str(ts),
        "x-api-key": YOUR_API_KEY
    }
)
print(userdata.json())
```

and that's the error message:
`{'success': False, 'code': -1002, 'message': 'invalid api key.'}`

But I am pretty sure, that my api-key is right, I tried a new one and that didnt work either.
I tried to follow the instructions on the website: https://kronosresearch.github.io/wootrade-documents/#example
But I am not that familiar with hashing my authentication, because the exchanges I used before had either some examples in python or a package to download, so I am not sure, what I did wrong.
I am thankful for any help I can get!
Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also send your params in requests, the following code is how I make it work to get account orders:

```
import requests
import datetime
import time
import hmac
import hashlib
from collections import OrderedDict


class Client():
    def __init__(self, api_key=None, api_secret=None):
        self.api_key = api_key
        self.api_secret = api_secret
        self.base_api = "https://api.woo.network/v1/"

    def get_signature(self, params, timestamp):
        query_string = '&'.join(["{}={}".format(k, v) for k, v in params.items()]) + f"|{timestamp}"
        signature = hmac.new(
            self.api_secret.encode('utf-8'),
            query_string.encode('utf-8'),
            hashlib.sha256
        ).hexdigest()
        return signature

    def get_orders(self, symbol):
        url = self.base_api + "orders/"
        params = {
            "symbol": symbol
        }
        params = OrderedDict(sorted(params.items()))
        timestamp = str(int(time.time() * 1000))
        signature = self.get_signature(params, timestamp)
        headers = {
            'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            'x-api-key': self.api_key,
            'x-api-signature': signature,
            'x-api-timestamp': timestamp,
            'cache-control': 'no-cache'
        }
        resp = requests.get(url=url, params=params,  headers=headers).json()
        print(resp)
```

If you have any further questions, please join the WOOTRADE official telegram group and ask the admins~
(Please don't do any transfer if anyone ask you to do so in the group!)

Telegram: [T.me/wootrade](http://T.me/wootrade)

Or you can try this python library for wootrade API

https://github.com/wanth1997/python-wootrade?fbclid=IwAR15onh2IX4KX85ahG-hJjXspFwhrTLHSNWGyW7n8c5kAw_8U4cQocbZEEc